# How to delete the previous print() using '\b'

Tags: python

Im using Pyautogui to print mouse's current position.

After i print the first coordinates, i want to delete it instantly and print the next coordinates.

```
import pyautogui as p
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

try:
    while True:
        x, y = p.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='') #printing current position
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True) #deleting previous print

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nDone')
```

Instead of deleting the previous print, it prints the next coordinates with some weird  squares.

Comment: This is dependent on the interface of your display device.

Comment: The newline will take it to the next line.

Comment: Remove the `\n` and you'll likely get what you want.  The `\n` is what's triggering it to advance.

Comment: @PeterWood replacing the first print() with print(positionStr, end='') still doesnt work

Comment: I think Prune's comment is important. Not all consoles handle backspace characters being written to them.  They probably *should*, but there's no guarantee that they will. So maybe you can fix your issue not by changing your code, but by changing how you run it (e.g. using a real command line rather than an interactive shell in an IDE, perhaps).

Comment: Okay, thank you all!!

Comment: @gripis but you got rid of the `\r` as well as the `\n`.