# Chapter 18: Python Auto GUI

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn to use pyautogui from the pdf book: how to automate the boring stuff.

I'm having an issue getting my code to overwrite the current mouse position by using the backspace /b character.

Instead of moving the cursor position back, it seems to print these some weird characters instead. (e.g.  somehow it does not show in this page, but the symbol can be described as a black box with a white circle in the middle)

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

```
import pyautogui
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

try:
    while True:
        x,y=pyautogui.position()
        positionStr='X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nDone.')
```

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What characters does it seem to print?

Answer (score 0):

\b is technically a control character and can be printed because it is a character. (It looks weird because it's meant to never be seen) It does not do 'Backspace' unless the program you use it in knows how to handle the control character.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question at the following link.

[How to delete the previous print() using '\b'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187286/how-to-delete-the-previous-print-using-b)

Apparently, it is a display issue of the interactive shell. Running the code in a real command line seems to avoid this problem.

Thanks, all!